# Улучшить перевод сообщения о куки и т.п. в подвале сайта

Tags: предложение, статус-завершено, локализация, уведомления, cookie

При открытии сайта в приватном окне можно увидеть такой баннер в подвале страницы:

> [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

В оригинале там:

> By using our site, you acknowledge that you have read and understand
>   our $cookiePolicyStart$Cookie Policy$linkEnd$,
>   $privacyPolicyStart$Privacy Policy$linkEnd$, and our $tosStart$Terms
>   of Service$linkEnd$

Как минимум убрать повторяющееся "вы" и акцентировать внимание на "нашем" сайте.

Предлагаю:

> Используя наш сайт, вы подтверждаете, что прочитали и поняли
>   $cookiePolicyStart$политику о куки$linkEnd$,
>   $privacyPolicyStart$политику конфиденциальности$linkEnd$ и
>   $tosStart$пользовательское соглашение$linkEnd$.

Традусёр: https://ru.traducir.win/string/10773

Comment: На русскоязычной версии это сообщение вообще можно удалить. У нас же вроде закона такого ещё нет....

Comment: @AlexanderSemikashev по поводу куки? Может и нет. Но на SOru не только из России заходят.

Comment: Утвердил, можно звать модератора с красной меткой.